# Is it possible to delay an assignment operation

Tags: prolog, constraints, eclipse-clp

I have a small script/code and i want to impose some `active` constraints. In the code shown below, i have `P[I,J] #= E` and in the next line `Result[I,E] #= J` but this is throwing an `instantiation error` because `E` is not instantiated.

For these constraints i need to know what value is at `P[I,J]`, so if i write it as `E is P[I,J]` then offcourse i will not get an `instantiation error(incase i suspend next two constraints with suspend, e.g suspend:(P[I,J] #= E)` but will it effect the activeness of a constraint because the `assignment` will not be delayed but only constraint will be delayed. Is there any alternative way to impose this constraint?

```
multifor([I,J] ,[1,1],[N,N]),param(P,ResultFirst),foreach(E,_) do
            E #:: 1..9,
            P[I,J] #= E,
           (ResultFirst[I,E] #= J),
```

Comment: why do you need to delay the index assignment? Indeed when you have a suspension, the delayed assignment will happen automatically!

Comment: @OmG `suspend` library does not impose active constraints and even using the `suspend` would not solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't say that using any specific library, I said that you have an extra level that you don't need to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if one could just write it the way you have done, but unfortunately this is currently not supported (assuming you are using [ECLiPSe](https://eclipseclp.org)).  If the array index `E` is uninstantiated at constraint setup time, you have to use an [element/3](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/element-3.html) constraint.  So, instead of

```
ResultFirst[I,E] #= J
```

write

```
element(E, ResultFirst[I], J)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that `ResultFirst[i]` will take a one dimensional array out(of 2D array) and then element/3 will be invoked. Is it correct?

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution for a column? I mean for `ResultFirst[E,J] #= I`? I can't figure out how to get the colum out without row.

Comment: Ok I used this trick and it seems fine :)  ` element(E,ResultFirst[1..N,J],I)`

Comment: If you have at least ECLiPSe version 7.0, you can abbreviate the `1..N` with a `*`, i.e. `element(E,ResultFirst[*,J],I)`